# Can a macOS app built with Xcode 9 work on macOS versions earlier than 10.13?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, compatibility

I am making a macOS app with Xcode 9.0.1 and Swift 4. I want to ask if the released app (.app file) can work on macOS earlier than 10.13 (e.g., 10.9 or 10.11) or will it work only on macOS 10.13?

Comment: macOS 10.9 and 10.11 are *earlier*, not *later* than 10.13. What is the Deployment Target of your program? That is the oldest version of macOS your program will run on.

Comment: It is difficult answer without knowing complete details. In general we will be able to support multiple OS versions.

Comment: Are you sure that you wanted to say "later"? Asking because 10.9 and 10.11 are technically earlier, not later than 10.13.

Comment: Yes earlier sorry, Deployment Target is 10.13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the "Deployment Target" for your "Project" settings (not your target settings) and it will build an app that supports that version and later. E.g. if you set the deployment target to 10.11, it will support 10.11 at later (e.g. 10.11, 10.12, 10.13, etc.).

Note, when you first discover this drop down box, you may be tempted to set it to the earliest possible OS version, but realize that the more versions that you want to retroactively support, the more work that entails. You'll have to write conditional code wherever you want to use newer OS features and likewise wherever older targets need to use now-deprecated APIs.

FYI, there are a few constraints introduced by various Xcode features. E.g. Swift, itself, requires macOS 10.9 or later. Storyboards require macOS 10.10 or later. Etc.

In short, set your deployment target, but do so with awareness of the cost-benefit trade-off that decision may entail.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there also a limit imposed by using Swift? What's the earliest version of macOS that supports Swift?

Comment: Swift requires 10.9 or later. Storyboards require 10.10 or later.

Answer (score 0):

The earliest version of macOS that will be able to run your application is equal to your Deployment Target setting, which can be found in Build Settings of your .xcodeproj in Xcode.

This way, application built with Deployment Target set to 10.13 will not launch on 10.12 and earlier.

Not to be confused with Target SDK.